# Формула стандартного отклонения

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

На хабре есть статья нейронные сети для начинающих. https://habr.com/ru/post/312450/ Там есть формула MSE [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные: I1=1, I2=0, w1=0.45, w2=0.78 ,w3=-0.12 ,w4=0.13 ,w5=1.5 ,w6=-2.3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кто может пояснить обозначения на данной формуле, на примере использовавшемся в статье:

```
H1input = 1*0.45+0*-0.12=0.45
H1output = sigmoid(0.45)=0.61

H2input = 1*0.78+0*0.13=0.78
H2output = sigmoid(0.78)=0.69

O1input = 0.61*1.5+0.69*-2.3=-0.672
O1output = sigmoid(-0.672)=0.33

O1ideal = 1 (0xor1=1)

Error = ((1-0.33)^2)/1=0.45
```

Результат — 0.33, ошибка — 45%.

Что значит n,i1,a2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нейронные сети (НС) состоят из слоев и обычно имеют:

- один входной ("**In**put") слой
- 1+ скрытых ("**H**idden") слоев
- один выходной ("**O**utput") слой.

Аббревиатуры:

- `I<i>` - `i`-ый нейрон *входного* слоя
- `H<i>` - `i`-ый нейрон *скрытого* слоя
- `O<i>` - `i`-ый нейрон *выходного* слоя

`n` число строк / экземпляров / образцов поданных НС на вход

Функция ошибки позволяет оценить среднюю величину ошибки или отклонения предсказанных значений от реальных. В приведенной формуле `i1` - это реальное значение, а `a1` - предсказанное значение из обучающей выборки:

```
Error = ((1-0.33)^2)/1=0.45
```

в данной формуле НС подали на вход всего один экземпляр (`n == 1`) и `1` - это реальное значение и обучающего набора, а `0.33` - предсказанное значение

Comment: реальное значение это типо эталонная единица которую мы используем? Мы подали один экземпляр выходного слоя, это O1 output? Тоесть у нас может быть и не 1 выходной нейрон?

Comment: @GnomSkull, обучающая выборка состоит из двух частей - данных которые подаются на вход и эталонные данные, которые НС должна предсказывать. Под "реальными данными" я подразумевал эталонные значения. Значения на выходе слоя зависят от активирующей функции. В вашем случае используется сигмоид, который может принимать любое значение в диапазоне `(0, 1)`

Comment: понял. И еще вопрос возник почему мы из таблицы исключающего или выбераем из 4 комбинаций именно эту O1ideal = 1 (0xor1=1)?

Comment: @GnomSkull, просто выбрали предпоследнюю строку из таблицы для проверки. `O1ideal` - эталонное значение.

Comment: то есть мы можем любую строку выбрать и значение ее и будет являться эталонным для нас? Может тогда мне имеет смысл написать проверку сразу для 4 строк?

Comment: @GnomSkull, чем больше вы будете пробовать тем быстрее разберётесь ;)